# A open source and easy-to-use solution to Symantec Backup Exec

Tags: backup, tape, open-source

i need a open source and easy-to-use solution to replace Symantec Backup Exec.
Basically i only make tape-based backups in a Powervault TL2000

Answer (score 2):

This is purely subjective as I'm sure other people have their own preference but I've used in production:

- Bacula - http://blog.bacula.org/
- Bacula Web (GUI for above) - http://www.bacula-web.org/

We were using that to do tape drive backups if that helps?

Comment: I also use Bacula, it can manage tape backups well. Another alternative is Bareos, a Bacula fork.

Comment: I would also recommend Bacula; it's not all that easy to set up, but once set up it just runs with no fuss.